# how to resize the picture returned by facebook in FLASK

Tags: python, facebook, flask

I am using flask-dance to login with facebook
and then I want to get something from facebook

```
facebook_user = facebook.get('me?fields=id, name, picture').json()
picture = facebook_user['picture']['data']['url']
```

but the size of picture returned is 50X50, It is very small

https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=203369520283932&height=50&width=50&ext=1529257913&hash=AeSMeR1ll5dTATyo

I am trying to change the height=50&width=50 in url to height=256&width=256, but it doesn't work, how can I resize the picture

Comment: Yes. You can't just change the URL. Ask for a bigger image instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`me?fields=id,name,picture` is a *GraphQL query*, and `picture` is a [User Picture object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/), which comes with a few *parameters*.

One of those is `type`, which lets you specify a predefined size for the picture:

```
me?fields=id, name, picture.type(large)
```

The default is to give you `picture.type(small)`.

Or you could use the `width` and `height` fields to request a specific size:

```
me?fields=id, name, picture.width(125).height(150)
```

The returned image dimensions can be larger than the specified size; the idea is that the image will 'fit' the dimensions.

You could even request *multiple sizes*, each [returned under a different name](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields); I'm showing *just* the `picture` definitions here, not the whole `me?fields=...` specification:

```
picture.type(small).as(smallpic),picture.width(1024).height(768).as(hdpic)
```

at which point the result with have URLs for both `smallpic` and `hdpic`.